# He teaches Mathematics to me

Tags: grammar

Are these two sentences interchangeable?

1) "He teaches me Mathematics"

2) "He teaches Mathematics to me"

Comment: "Mathematics" does not need to be capitalized in your examples.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

It is a general property of ditransitive verbs (eg *give*, *tell*, *show*, *explain*. *teach*) that they have two different sentence frames:

> teach *something* to *somebody*

and

> teach *somebody* *something*.

There is some limitation on the kind of phrase that can be the *somebody* in the second form - personal pronouns, and names, are usually fine; but more complex noun phrases are less common.

Comment: +1 for the specific point about the *truly* ditransitive form (indirect object "fronted", with no preposition) being more likely with pronouns. I'd say it's somewhat less common with ordinary nouns / names, and *much* less common with longer NPs (the longer, the less likely).

Comment: Thanks. Might it be better to say "I teach English to my six year old son" than "I teach my six year old son English" since the phrase is long? I think that structure is ok with long phrases too as long as we do the intonation properly.

Comment: @derememo, I find that works either way round. But if you put his name in as well, I would find "I teach my six year old  son Wiliam English" awkward. I think it is partly to do with the possiibilities for misparsing. Its hard to see a parse in which 'English' after 'son' could be absorbed into that constituent, but once you've said name, the possible grammar is much freer.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences use different grammar. But in this case, the meaning is the same.